# Optional typing for more than a single type

Tags: python, typing

Since the documentation only uses `Optional` with a single type (`Optional[X]`), I was wondering if Union is required if I have an argument that accepts either a string, a list, or None.

```py
def func(
    arg: Optional[str, list]
)
```

```py
def func(
    arg: Optional[Union[str, list]]
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: I first wrote this, but this is incorrect:

"Since `Optional[...]` is shorthand for `Union[..., None]`, they are essentially the same, and you can just use `Optional[str, list]`, since that's the same as `Union[str, list, None]`."

In fact, Python currently only accepts a single argument for `Optional[X]`.

So, your valid options are:

```
def func(
    arg: Optional[Union[str, list]]
)

def func(
    arg: Union[str, list, None]
)

def func(
    arg: Union[str, list] | None
)
```

Some type checkers do seem to accept the `Optional[str, list]`, but using it will cause an exception at runtime:

```
TypeError: typing.Optional requires a single type. Got (<class 'str'>, <class 'list'>).
```

Comment: Totally agree with that. However, I realized that linters such as Pylance and MyPy would raise an error suggesting that Optional[...] must have exactly one type argument, but Black and Flake8 does not raise such an error. I think this probably a preference of style for now. Could you add this to your answer to make it more complete?

Comment: Your comment caused me to revisit the code and try and run it. As it turns out, the PyCharm type checker accepts `Optional[]` with multiple arguments, and it matched my expectation, but Python (I currently run 3.10.2) does not actually run it. See the updated answer.

Comment: Cheers! I didn't realized that Python would raise TypeError during runtime as well.